# How to install private NPM module from specific branch and specific tag

Tags: git, npm, npm-install

Does **npm** always pull from the master branch if a branch isn't specified in the dependency? What if I have another branch, say `develop` and I tag the commit there? I know **npm** will update from a specific branch, if written like

```
"private-repo": "git+ssh://git@github.com:myaccount/myprivate.git#develop"
```

but what if I want to pull a specific tag from that branch? Because just specifying the tag, like

```
"private-repo": "git+ssh://git@github.com:myaccount/myprivate.git#v1.0.1"
```

did not work (the `master` branch does not have the tagged commit. Just the `develop` branch has it). `I got a fatal: ambiguous argument 'v1.0.1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` which leads me to the thought that it tries to find the specified tag in a branch that does not have it (which must be the `master` branch, since I've got only these 2 branches).

So, is there a way to specify both the branch and the git-tag from which to update?

Answer (score 2):

There's not any direct link between branches & tags. In a way, tags are just branches that do not move when commiting.

You should be able to checkout (or npm install) any branche or any tag (or any commit ref) you refer to.

It looks like `v1.0.1` is **not** a tag (neither a branch) of your repository. If you want a *semver* selection of the right version, you have to prefix it with `semver:`.

Take a look at npm official documentation about [package dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies). It explains all the way to use git repositories as package source :

```
<protocol>://[<user>[:<password>]@]<hostname>[:<port>][:][/]<path>[#<commit-ish> | #semver:<semver>]
```

```
git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/cli.git#v1.0.27
git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/cli#semver:^5.0
git+https://isaacs@github.com/npm/cli.git
git://github.com/npm/cli.git#v1.0.27
```